# HTTPs to HTTP Redirection

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https

Currently, have one webserver(Domain - example1.com) and an appserver integrated through webplugin. Entire communication happens through HTTP. For ex. When a user hits URL http://example1.com/hello, it will load content available in /hello directory of appserver.

To make it secure, ALB with url(example2.com) has been set up and when user hits ALB url https://example2.com it will point to webserver(example1.com).

Need guidance/steps to take it forward, once request reached to webserver from ALB, it should automatically redirect to http://example1.com/hello, but URL in the browser should appear as https://example2.com/hello

Referred different online documents, but couldn't able to take it forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

If you redirect then the URL that you redirect to will be displayed in the browser's address bar.

---

You could make `https://example2.com` serve up nothing but an `<iframe>` that points to `http://example1.com` but this would:

- Defeat the purpose of using HTTPS
- Be alerted as insecure or blocked entirely by browsers

---

You could make `https://example2.com` a reverse proxy pointing to `http://example1.com` but then the browser would communicate securely with `https://example2.com` and then `example2.com` would forward the same data **insecurely** to `http://example1.com`.

This is probably OK if `https://example2.com` and `http://example1.com` are on the same computer (or at least in the same secure network) but is otherwise going to give users a false sense of security which could result in some very bad PR down the road.

Answer (score -2):

you said you want URL in the browser appears as https://example2.com/hello, I think this is not possible.

But there is one way you can try:

using a  that fill the entire page, and write "http://example1.com/hello" to the src of the .
Note that https may not work properly...

May this can help you~